# Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 installed - is SQL Server included?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 installed (on Windows 10) and need access to SQL Server. I thought the server was included in the installation of VS, but begin to suspect that I was wrong.

I can see programs under Control panel, like SQL Server 2012 Native Client, SQL Server Express 2014 Localdb, some different management tools, etc. 
I concluded that the SQL server and management tools were integrated, but can not run the server via my VS:

> Can not connect to ... A network-related or instance-specific error ocurred while Establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configurated to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, Error: 40 – could not open a connection to SQL-Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 2 ... Unable to find the file.

I realized that I need to configure the firewall in some way, perhaps even make further adjustments/configurations. But I also think that I still have to install? How do I make these configurations?

Do I need both the SQL Server and Management? Or is it enough with the VS for management? If installation is needed, does it matter which version I choose? (I have access to DreamSpark: Web Edition, Express, ordinary etc. - 2014 and 2016). As you can tell I am a total beginner and need some help to point me in the right direction…

Comment: Have you tried connecting to: (localdb)\mssqllocaldb ?

Comment: No, but I worked it out by in Server Configuration set - Database Engine services:  NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE. Then it works to connect with the  mycomputername\SQLEXPRESS. Finally! Thanks!